# tensorflow slim and half precision

Tags: tensorflow

Is there a way to define `dtype=tf.half` in slim library? In general, lets say I want to train with `fp16` i.e. want all tensors to be of half precision. Is there a way to specify this to `tf.slim`?

Answer (score -1):

For half precision in tensorflow use: `tf.float16`
Example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.contrib.slim as slim
weights = slim.variable('weights', shape=[10, 1], dtype=tf.float16)
```